# Phone number validation which contains +** ***-***-**** (Plus following with Two digit country code with 10 digit mobile number)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a functionality that has a form which contains a mobile number field. The requirement is to allow the following format for the mobile number field:

```
+** ***-***-****
```

(Plus following with Two digit country code with 10 digit mobile number) I tried with the below regular expression but wasn't able to produce required result.

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/"
```

Can anyone guide me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function phonenumber(inputtxt) {
  var phoneno = /^\+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
  if(inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
    //return true;
    alert("true");
  }  
  else {  
    //alert("message");
    //return false;
    alert("false");
  }
}

phonenumber("+91 111 111 1111");
phonenumber("+11-223-333-4444");
phonenumber("984656462464");
```

If you want to accept spaces or dots in between like +91 333 333 4444 then you can change ?[-] to ?[-. ]

Comment: Hi Vikas thanks for the answer it seem to be working but with a bit of issue when I start typing +91 the error message will pop up and when I complete full number error message will go. That means the regular expression is not accepting + at the start.

Comment: Have a variable to store input value and once the user submits then pass that value to the method to check if it passes the validation or not and depending on that show the error message.

Comment: 984656462464 number is also being allowed with your regular expression which should not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer. Check it. Also, you understood how to fix your first comment problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `ng-pattern="/^\+[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/"`

Comment: Add small explanation even though code is explanatory